# spark scala maven build error from eclipse - Object X is not a member of package Y

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven

```
package com.mycomp.etl.main

import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.xml.XML
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import com.mycomp.ref.sparkframework.init.xmlLoaderImpl
```

Hello
I am building using maven in eclipse and getting below error

error: object ref is not a member of package com.mycomp
[ERROR] import com.mycomp.ref.sparkframework.init.xmlLoaderImpl

Above mycomp.ref class is in other jar which i have added as external jar in project properties/libraries, pointing to my local destination
This other jar is also available in jar folder outside src

I tried *root* based on other post from SO, but its not helping

Can you please help point out issue

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<yourjarfilename> -DgroupId=<yourpackagename> -DartifactId=<yourartifactid> -Dversion=<jarversionnumber> -Dpackaging=jar
```

This solved my issue 
This way you add that jar to maven path